# How to test seasonality of time series using One way ANOVA test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, statsmodels

I did perform a one way ANOVA test on my data, I'm having problems understand the results, my p-value is 0.0721 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The null hypothesis of an anova is that all group means are the same, hence, in your case the null hypothesis is that there is no seasonality. You got a quite small p value which doesn't cross the conventional alpha level of .05 or .01. Although there are some people who [emphasize that dichotomous significance testing has no ontological basis. That is, we want to underscore that, surely, God loves the .06 nearly as much as the .05](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4f0d/47b625c09a0206511f425256b7dc1aa09922.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiZm4_Zk_rhAhXPPFAKHaE0ABAQFjAAegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw3BxjdriD4ck8kjg-cAQ9GD). So I would say you have some evidence that there might be some seasonality. But keep in mind, that even a significant p value doesn't tell you how relevant the effect is since in case of a big sample size little differences can be significant. You may want to read more about seasonality detection [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/310230/how-can-i-identify-seasonality-in-this-plot), for example.
Also, try to be more precise, i.e. provide some data, explain what you try to do or show a plot. I guess the lack of all this information is why your question got downvoted.

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback, It's what i am looking for. I have another question if you can help please